# EDGE does not accept specific stylesheet

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

So, I have an issue positioning an absolute element specifically for all IE versions.

```
.flowplayer.fixed-controls .fp-controls, .flowplayer.fixed-controls.is-mouseover .fp-controls {
    bottom: -30px;
}
```

I want the bottom parameter to be set like this bottom: -18px; (only on IE).
I loaded my modification to a sepate .css file setting the bottom to imporant calling it like this

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `if IE` conditional tag only works for versions 9 and below. You cannot target IE10, 11 or Edge with it.

Comment: @Aziz thanks you for your time ! I ended up using
`    @supports (-ms-accelerator:true) {
  .flowplayer.fixed-controls .fp-controls, .flowplayer.fixed-controls.is-mouseover .fp-controls { 
        bottom: -18px; 
  } `